# content hugging does not work

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have a UIView that has a subview 
I want the yellow view to grow only as the length of the label is
unfortunately it grows to the maximum width of the screen minus the forced margins i gave it between the white view and the yellow view left and right margins

i've set the content hugging priority to 502 , 501 on the white and yellow view

how do i make this work ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have understood from your question is you want your yellow view to have intrinsic content size i.e its size should depend on the size of label.For this follow these steps -

1 .Add following constraints to the yellow view

```
           a.Center horizontally in container.

           b.Center vertically in container.
```

2. Now to the image view add following constraints

   ```
          a. Leading and Trailing space with respect to yellow view.

          b. Top space with respect to yellow view and Bottom space with respect to label.
   ```
3. Now to the label add following constraints

   ```
         a. Leading and trailing space with respect to yellow view.
         b. Bottom space with respect to yellow view.
   ```

This will give you desired result.Now label have leading and trailing space pinned to the yellow view, so as label will grow, yellow view will automatically grow.

[image: You can see the required constraints added in the screenshot.]